# Link nodejs app to Rethinkdb from another container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, rethinkdb

I made two 2 containers, one for the RethinkDB and one for a nodejs app.

I want to connect my nodejs app to this RethinkDB but everytime I try get an error

> Error:{"message":"Failed to connect to localhost:58015\nFull error:\n{\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\"

But I can connect the same nodejs app running without Docker to the RethinkDB, with the open port (`58015`).

My Docker compose config look like this

```
# Rethink DB
rethink:
  build: docker/rethinkdb
  container_name: rethink
  ports:
    - 58080:8080
    - 58015:28015
    - 59015:29015

# NodeJS
nodejs:
  build: docker/nodejs
  container_name: nodejs
  ports:
    - 53000:3000
    - 55000:5000
  depends_on:
    - rethink
```

To connect my app to the db I set the host and port inside a JS config file

```
database: {
    servers: [
        {
            host: process.env.DB_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost',
            port: process.env.DB_PORT_28015_TCP_PORT || 28015
        }
    ],
    name: 'atlas'
},
```

I tried with RethinkDB port (`28015`) and with my open port (`58015`) without success.

I tried to link this two containers with `links`, `network_mode`, without success too.

Every solutions I tried don't work.

I think my Rethink container is not ready when the nodejs app try to connect. I really don't understand the problem, if this not this.
The nodejs app is running with pm2

How can I made this app connect to my db ?

Comment: Have you tried to connect with address: rethink and port: 28015?

Comment: No, and this is now working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For you config, you should use
`# Rethink DB
    rethink:
      build: docker/rethinkdb
      container_name: rethink
      ports:
        - 58080:8080
        - 58015:28015
        - 59015:29015
    # NodeJS
    nodejs:
      build: docker/nodejs
      container_name: nodejs
      ports:
        - 53000:3000
        - 55000:5000
      links:
        - rethink
      depends_on:
        - rethink`

and in JS code
`database: {
    servers: [
        {
            host: process.env.DB_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR || 'rethink',
            port: process.env.DB_PORT_28015_TCP_PORT || 28015
        }
    ],
    name: 'atlas'
},`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, one Docker container will not see the other unless specifically **linked** and using the same **net**:

```
docker run \
   --name ${NEWAPP} \
   --restart=always \
   --env MYAPPPAR=${PROJ} \
   -v /var/log/docker/node/logs:/usr/src/app/log \
   --link myapp_rethink_1:myapp_rethink_1 \
   --net myapp_default \
   -p ${PORT}:9000 \
   -d ${NEWAPP}
```

So you need both --net and --link:

- --link format is sourcecontainername:containeraliasname
- --net  so that containers can find each other with internal DNS / containername. You can check network with 'docker network ls'

Comment: I know and I tried but since docker compose file 2, every containers are in the same network (`project_default`) and link is deprecated  so I'm using `depends_on`. The problem was the connection host.

Answer (score 0):

When using newer versions of docker-compose, your services will be configured to run on the same network.

The top level service name in your 'docker-compose.yml' will become the host that needs to be specified, when connecting to RethinkDB from your app:

```
    # docker-compose.yml

    version: '3.2'
    Services:
      web:
        build: .
        links: db
        ...
      db:
        image: rethinkDB
        ...
```

Using the example above, you can connect to RethinkDB by using the host named 'db', within the app configuration file:

```
    module.exports = {
      rethinkdb: {
        host: 'db',
        port: 28015
     }
   };
```